# Simplify expression to Integer

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I have the following function:

```
f[n_]:=(n-1) E Gamma[n,1];
```

I know that this expression always evaluates to an Integer, but *Mathematica* doesn't always output the result as one:

```
f[3]
f[3]//FullSimplify
f[1000]
f[1000]//FullSimplify
```

Output is as follows:

```
2 E Gamma[3,1]
10
999 E Gamma[1000,1]
999 E Gamma[1000,1]
```

In the case of small `n`, like `3` above, `FullSimplify` successfully forces *Mathematica* to express the result as an integer. I would like to do the same for large `n` as well; how do I make this happen?

If it's not possible to make this happen, then how might I at least compare the result with another integer? For instance, I wish to check if `f[1000]==<extremely large integer here>`.

Comment: Have you tried `FunctionExpand[]`?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I just tried wrapping `f[1000]` with `FunctionExpand` as per your suggestion, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: `FunctionExpand` only works up to `Gamma[29, 1]`. If you want to go higher, you can use the definition `f[a_, z_] := 2 E Integrate[t^(a - 1) E^-t, {t, z, Infinity}]`. But that only works up to `f[114, 1]`. Then you start getting the result back in terms of `Gamma` again.

Comment: @SimonRochester - Thanks for the additional information. I am interested in knowing the internal reason why *Mathematica* behaves this way.

Comment: Since you know it's an integer, `Round@...`

Comment: @ciao - Indeed that would work and it is what I've been doing thus far, but in principle I shouldn't have to manually provide that information. There could well be other problems in the future where I have not proven by hand that the result is an integer, and I wish to understand how to use *Mathematica* better.

Answer (score 2):

(Caveat: I did the following experiments with paper, a pen, and Alpha, but I believe it should also work in *Mathematica*.)

Through the use of a few well-known identities relating the incomplete gamma function and the partial sums of the exponential function, we have the following formula:

```
f[n_Integer] := (n - 1) Sum[(n - k - 1)! Binomial[n - 1, n - k - 1], {k, 0, n - 1}]
```

This particular formulation manifestly shows that `f[n]` has to be an integer for positive integer `n`.

In particular, feeding the corresponding expression for `f[1000]` into Alpha showed an integer result that goes like `1092708…2913980`; I don't see why *Mathematica* cannot do this evaluation as well.

Comment: I actually came across my `f` given in the question by the reverse process-- I started with an equivalent expression to the one you give here (expressed with factorials instead of the `Binomial` function) and *Mathematica* evaluates it symbolically to give the `f` in my question.

Comment: Although technically a solution to my specific problem, this answer doesn't really get to the root of the issue: I want to know how to force *Mathematica* into evaluating expressions like this in situations where I do not have another form for the function which I can use.

Comment: I suppose my point here is that sometimes closed forms are not useful; in this particular case, it is much less obvious that the closed form is supposed to be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree there seems to be something lacking here; I mean that there *should* be a way to get an exact integer expansion of this expression so long as it is within the capabilities of *Mathematica* to compute it.  I haven't found that way.

We can at least check if an expression is numerically equivalent to a given number of places:

```
fix[extra_Integer: 20][n_?NumericQ] := 
 With[{rou = Round @ n},
   If[N[n, IntegerLength @ rou + extra] == rou, rou, n]
 ]

f[35] // fix[]
```

> ```
> 27285882395011537935428754460868944562090
> ```

```
f[1000] // fix[] // IntegerLength
```

> ```
> 2569
> ```

You can specify a different amount of extra precision besides the default 20:

```
f[18] // fix[2000]   (* 2000 extra digits in the numeric comparison *)
```

> ```
> 16436597430879730
> ```